# Soma valor ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Como faço para somar no `ng-repeat` a quantidade `itensQtd` quando for da mesmo `(id)` da coluna `itensOportunidade`?

Conforme exemplo da imagem.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
/* Lista oportunidade */
$scope.listaOportunidade = [];
var carregaOportunidade = function() {
  $http.get("models/readOportunidade.php").then(function(response) {
    $scope.listaOportunidade = response.data;
  });
};
carregaOportunidade();
```

```html
<ul class="mb-0">
  <li style="font-size: 13px; padding:10px;" ng-repeat="oportunidade in listaOportunidade | orderBy: 'prospectNome' | betweenDate:'oportunidadePrevisao':startDate:endDate | dateRange:'oportunidadePrevisao':startDate:endDate | filter:pedido | filter: item | filter:vm.selectCidade track by $index">
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading text-center" ng-mouseenter="tooltip()">
        <a href="" class="text-info font-weight-bold" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Detalhes Oportunidade">
                                        {{oportunidade.prospectNome}}
                                    </a><br><br>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 mb-0 mt-0" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
              <button class="btn-outline-secondary border-0 btn-sm font-weight-bold" style="cursor: help" ng-init="checkId($index)">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>{{oportunidade.itensQtd}}
                                                </button>
              <button class="btn-outline-secondary border-0 btn-sm font-weight-bold" style="cursor: help" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Total Receita">
                                                    {{oportunidade.produtoPreco | currency}}
                                                </button>
              <button class="btn-outline-secondary border-0 btn-sm font-weight-bold" style="cursor: help" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tipo Pedido">
                                                    {{oportunidade.oportunidadeTipo}}
                                                </button>
              <button class="btn-outline-secondary border-0 btn-sm font-weight-bold" style="cursor: help" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Previsão Fechamento">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> {{oportunidade.oportunidadePrevisao |
                                                    date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
                                                </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-12 mb-0 mt-2 text-right">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Negócio Perdido :("><i
                                                            class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i></button>
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Negócio Ganho :)"><i
                                                            class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Você quer mostrar aonde a informação? falta esclarecer mais!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic vai ser exibida na li > button

Answer (score 0):

```js
 angular.forEach($scope.listaOportunidade, function(v, k){
            $scope.total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < v.itensQtd.length; i++) {
                $scope.total += v.itensQtd[i]
            }
        });
```

Eai, 
você pode fazer um for para percorrer a coluna do itensId

```js
 var total = 0
 var itens = $scope.listaOportunidade.itensId;

for (var i = 0; i < itens.length; i++) {
  total += itens[i]
}

console.log(total)
```